# How to number things in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, korean-to-english, numbers

I train in a Korean martial art.  We have sets of techniques that we call off in half English, half Korean.  I am wondering how to say them entirely in Korean. 
For example:

기본권법 基本拳法 Gi Bon Gwon Beop - basic unarmed fighting principles

삼보대련 三步對練 Sam Bo Dae Ryeon - three-step sparring

We will call off things like "Sam Bo Dae Ryeon number 13".  I am wondering how one would call this off entirely in Korean.  I'm not even sure what to call this type of linguistic construct. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: You mean something like 삼보대련 13`번`?

Answer (score 2):

## Ordinals

### 番[<sub>번</sub>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%95%AA)

The most basic and universal word to give things their ordinals is an ordinal number marker noun “**`번(番)`**”, which sounds a bit casual.

> 삼보대련 1 번(삼보대련 일 번, 三步對練一番.)
>
> 삼보대련 **number** one

### 第[<sub>제</sub>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC)

You may also use “**`제(第)-`**,” which is an ordinal number marker prefix.

> 기본권법 제5(기본권법 제오, 基本拳法第五.)
>
> 기본권법 **the** fif**th**

---

## …for what?

### 式[<sub>식</sub>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%8F)

But come on, this is a martial art, what we need here is badassery. What you got is a set of *techniques*, or, 식(式)s. “**`식(式)`**” is a cool, common name for techniques in martial arts in countries the Sinosphere has.

> 기본권법 제3 식(기본권법 제삼 식, 基本拳法第三式.)
>
> 기본권법 the third **style/technique/posture**

- [杨氏太极拳 第一式·第二式 (양가태극권 제일 식·제이 식, the first & second techniques of Yang's Taichi.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS3kjz-jVTk)
- [市来崎大祐 - 24式太極拳 (이치키자키 다이스케 - 이십사식 태극권, Daisuke Ichikizaki's performance of Tai Chi with 24 techniques.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw1D5TugYTg)
- [양가태극권 16 식 (16 techniques of Yang's Tai Chi)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHSsPny5r9g)

### 章[<sub>장</sub>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%AB%A0)

“**장(章)**” means a “chapter.” You know, ancient martial arts were recorded and passed down in the form of books, which had several chapters for each of the techniques. It is a literary expression to emphasize the power of a technique in novels and cartoons, though. Ugh, well, forget about this.

> 무예제보 제5 장(무예제보 제오 장, 武藝諸譜第五章.)
>
> 무예제보 **chapter** five